# How to align the content with the navigation bar title in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Giving padding does not work. My content is not aligned with the navigation bar's title. I do not want to specify a fixed value. The red box is longer than the navigation bar and a little more to the left.

```
var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        
        .navigationBarTitle(_t("Photos"), displayMode: .automatic)
        .background(NavigationConfigurator { nc in
            
        })
}
```

[image]

Comment: As far as i know, there is no way.